# How to subtract time?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timedelta

How do I subtract a starting time in hours and minutes (e.g. `2:30`) from an ending time in hours and minutes (e.g. `5:15`) in Python?

```
lengthOfDay=datetime(endh,endm) - datetime.timedelta(starth,startm)
```

Comment: Was there a particular problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: If you subtract two `datetime` values, you get a `timedelta`.  If you subtract a `timedelta` from a `datetime`, you get a `datetime`.  What you've displayed as an example is the latter, but you asked for the former.